# Android Test = Opening Already Closed Database

Tags: android, sqlite, testing

I made an application that copies a database that has been premade and then allows you to run the various queries/methods for an SQLiteDatabase (insert, update, etc.) with SQLTest as its main activity. I then made a test (called SQLTestCase, which I know is no appropriate, but I'm new to testing) which has a test suite calling up a randomTest() method that randomly picks a test to perform. The odd thing is that I get an error saying:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object:        SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.example.sql2/databases/os.sqlite
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1310)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
at com.example.sql2.test.SQLTestCase.randomTest(SQLTestCase.java:236)
at com.example.sql2.test.SQLTestCase.testSuite(SQLTestCase.java:38)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

The error shows up on two lines of code:

```
public void testSuite()
{
    int length = 100;
    for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
    {
        randomTest(); // Here
    }
}

public void randomTest()
{
    ...
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRecords FROM" + SQLAdapter.TABLE_OS;
    Cursor cursor = activity.accessAdapter().accessHelper().accessDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null); //Here
            ...
```

I know that the problem lies on the initialization of the cursor, because by commenting that out, the test runs fine. Anyone know the problem? I looked over my code hoping to find a place where I closed the database early, but I don't see anything. I'll try and provide what you need. Let me know if there is more code necessary to solve this problem.

```
public class SQLTestCase extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SQLTest>
{
SQLTest activity;

public SQLTestCase()
{
    super(SQLTest.class);
}

protected void setUp() throws Exception
{
    super.setUp();
    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
    activity = getActivity();
}

    ...

public void testSuite()
{
    int length = 100;
    for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
    {
        randomTest();
    }
}

    ...
public void randomTest()
{
    String name = "", field = "";
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randOp = rand.nextInt(5);
    int randName, randField, id;
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRecords FROM" + SQLAdapter.TABLE_OS;
    Cursor cursor = activity.accessAdapter().accessHelper().accessDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);

    switch (randOp)
    {
    case 0:
        randName = rand.nextInt(45);
        name = getRandomName(randName);
        int nullNotNull = rand.nextInt(2);
        switch (nullNotNull)
        {
        case 0:
            field = null;
            break;
        case 1:
            randField = rand.nextInt(24);
            field = getRandomField(randField);
            break;
        }
        testInsert(name, field);
        break;
    case 1:
        id = rand.nextInt(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))); 
        //id = rand.nextInt(12)+1;
        testDelete(id);
        break;
    case 2:
        int selection = rand.nextInt(5);
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 0:
            randName = rand.nextInt(45);
            id = rand.nextInt(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            //id = rand.nextInt(12)+1;
            name = getRandomName(randName);
            testUpdate(id, name, "");
            break;
        default:
            randName = rand.nextInt(45);
            name = getRandomName(randName);
            randField = rand.nextInt(24);
            field = getRandomField(randField);
            id = rand.nextInt(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            //id = rand.nextInt(12)+1;
            testUpdate(id, name, field);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        id = rand.nextInt(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        //id = rand.nextInt(12)+1;
        testGet(id);
        break;
    case 4:
        testGetAll();
        break;
    }
}

}


public class SQLTest extends Activity
{
public SQLAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sqltest);
    adapter = new SQLAdapter(this);
    adapter.createDatabase();
    open();
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, thanks to Joel, I ended up creating a local database for the randomTest() method, which then called up the raw query:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRecords FROM " + SQLAdapter.TABLE_OS;
SQLiteDatabase db = activity.accessAdapter().accessHelper().getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

This worked (although I then realized this wasn't useful for the purposes of my project). Either way, if anyone else has a problem with using a cursor like this, this was the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this will help, but it is possible that you need to close the cursor each time you finish.  Try calling `cursor.close();`

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't seem to help. I know there is no cursor.open(), so I'm not sure how I could re-open it if I did. Wouldn't that logically not work, though, since you are for sure trying to use something already closed? Also, I get the feeling it has more to do with my database, based on the error.

Comment: Well, constructing a Cursor is the similar to calling open correct? I think regardless you should be calling close when you are done with it. Is there some reason you are not using an instance of SQLiteOpenHelper and calling getWritableDatabase()? I think that is the more standard way of doing things.

Comment: I actually am, just a few levels down. My application calls an adapter, which then calls the MySQLiteHelper class. For some reason, doing things that way proved more successful than my previous attempts. I tried calling up methods like insert() or delete() in MySQLiteHelper, but it seemed to work much better when I just left the duties of that class to creating and copying the database (which in terms of standard, is what I think Android intended the class to be used for).

Comment: Well I don't know what else to say.. you could try using a CursorLoader to initialize and then call,
Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
but I'm not sure that will change anything. Best of luck to you

Comment: I tried writing that like this:                                         CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(activity);
  Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
  cursor = activity.accessAdapter().accessHelper().accessDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);                                                              but that just gives me a NullPointerException.

Comment: I wonder if all of this has something to do with the state your activity is in when you are attempting to access the database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14295/discussion-between-nioshobu-and-joel)